# Objective-c UIScrollView appearing above custom view

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have folowing problem.
I got 2 views in my project,one is created programmicaly (and it has touch events) and another is interface view created via xib file.
I create

```
UIScrollView
```

in my ViewController and set it as view,and after I add  my views as subviews.
But I cant see that one that programmicaly created,only white screen and interface view..

Also can I disable somehow ScrollView's touchs intercepting? I want to add some sort of minimap for it.

Comment: Please show the code that creates the view.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight self.mw=[[mainView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass `CGRectZero` to your view's `initWithFrame:`, it gets created with the size of zero. You need to pass a rectangle where the view is to be displayed, using `CGRectMake`.

As far as handling touches goes, you can customize it in your subclass of the scroll view by intercepting `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:`. There is also a `delaysContentTouches` flag that lets you control the timing of the events sent to your handling code.

Comment: Thanks alot! And what about second question of disabling scroll view's touch intercepting?